# How to open "Class browser" in Pharo2

Tags: pharo

I am reading *Pharo by Example* the book.

Yet I didn't find the "Class browser" in my "World" menu in my Pharo2.

Is it replaced by the "System Browser"?

Comment: Pharo by Example has been update in line with Pharo 5 http://files.pharo.org/books/updated-pharo-by-example/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is. System browser is *Nautilus*, a new advanced alternative for old class browser created by Benjamin Van Ryseghem.

You can still open the old one in Pharo 2.0 by executing `Browser open` but I would highly recommend to use *Nautilus* which is default for 2.0 version of Pharo.

Comment: Note that Nautilus looks different to the browser in PBE but has the same functionality (Pharo does not seem to keep documentation in line with code)

Answer (score 4):

You should not use Pharo 2.0 to follow Pharo by Example book, it has it's own image, which is an older version of Pharo.
You can download the right image from here: http://pharobyexample.org/image/PBE-OneClick-1.1.app.zip

After finishing learning with it, you can then use 2.0 safely :)